# Updating ColdFusion

Tags: updates, windows-server-2012, coldfusion

I’m new to ColdFusion. We just deployed a new Dev server and I put ColdFusion 2016 fresh install on it. 
I have downloaded all five update .jar files. 
My main question is, Do I need to install each one sequentially, or are they cumulative updates, thus doing update 5 will include the previous four?
Additionally,

> ```
> <Drive:\jre\bin>java.exe -jar <Drive:\>/hotfix-005-303689.jar
> ```

1. When using this command, does it matter where the jar file is located?
2. After executing this command, will I need to restart the CF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes - the updates are cumulative. So you just need to apply the latest one and it will include the updates before it.

*When using this command, does it matter where the jar file is located?* - No, it does not matter where you put the jar file on your server. You will just need to reference it correctly when you execute it.

*After executing this command, will I need to restart the CF service?* - Yes, you should restart the ColdFusion service after applying any updates.

You should really follow the update's installation instructions when applying them. Sometimes they require different steps. The requisite steps should be outlined in the update's instructions. [For ColdFusion 2016 Update 5 those instructions are here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2016-update-5.html).